# How to do Java "glass stack" or "traversable stack"?

Tags: java, arrays, stack, tostring

I am supposed to implement a method `inspector()` that will be a glass/traversable stack in the following code. My books description is pretty vague and I have not found anything useful pertaining to the subject.

This is the books definition:

> In compiler construction, we need an observer method to examine stack
>   elements based on their location in the stack (the top of the stack is
>   considered location 1, the second element from the top is location 2,
>   and so on). This is sometimes called (colloquially) a "glass stack" or
>   (more formally) a "traversable stack". The definition of a stack is
>   exactly as we specify in this chapter, except we add a public method
>   named inspector that accepts an int argument indicating the location
>   to be returned. The method should return null if the argument
>   indicates an unused location.

Also, the `toString()` method at the bottom is supposed to report useful information about the stack as a string, I believe what I have is correct, but not 100% sure.

```
package ch03.stacks;

public class ArrayStack<T> implements BoundedStackInterface<T> 
{
  protected final int DEFCAP = 100; // default capacity
  protected T[] stack;              // holds stack elements
  protected int topIndex = -1;      // index of top element in stack

  public ArrayStack() 
  {
    stack = (T[]) new Object[DEFCAP];
  }

  public ArrayStack(int maxSize) 
  {
    stack = (T[]) new Object[maxSize];
  }

  public void push(T element)
  // Throws StackOverflowException if this stack is full,
  // otherwise places element at the top of this stack.
  {      
    if (!isFull())
    {
      topIndex++;
      stack[topIndex] = element;
    }
    else
      throw new StackOverflowException("Push attempted on a full stack.");
  }

  public void pop()
  // Throws StackUnderflowException if this stack is empty,
  // otherwise removes top element from this stack.
  {                  
    if (!isEmpty())
    {
      stack[topIndex] = null;
      topIndex--;
    }
    else
      throw new StackUnderflowException("Pop attempted on an empty stack.");
  }

  public T top()
  // Throws StackUnderflowException if this stack is empty,
  // otherwise returns top element from this stack.
  {                 
    T topOfStack = null;
    if (!isEmpty())
      topOfStack = stack[topIndex];
    else
      throw new StackUnderflowException("Top attempted on an empty stack.");
    return topOfStack;
  }

  public boolean isEmpty()
  // Returns true if this stack is empty, otherwise returns false.
  {              
    if (topIndex == -1) 
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }

  public boolean isFull()
  // Returns true if this stack is full, otherwise returns false.
  {              
    if (topIndex == (stack.length - 1)) 
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }

  public static void popSome(int count)
  {
      for(count > 0; count--)
            {
                if (count <= stack.size())
                {
                    stack.pop();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new StackUnderflowException("Not enough objects to pop");
                }
            }
  }

  public String toString()
  {
      return stack;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you have a question?  The assignment seems fairly straight-forward.

Comment: I don not quite understand what it wants. Thats my question.

Comment: If you do not understand what the assignment means, your best source of information is the professor or teaching assistant. We would just be guessing.

Comment: Apparently he wants you to describe an interface that can "observe" the contents of the stack, using a relative index from the top of the stack.  This would be a method like `T get(int index)`.

Comment: The question is to implement that inspector method to that class.

Comment: Yes?  If you can't figure out how to implement that method you should probably switch to art history.

Comment: (Look at the code you have.  The stack is implemented as an array and a top-of-stack index.  If you're asked for element 1 you'd return the one addressed by the top-of-stack index.  If you're asked for element 2 you'd return the element one position *earlier* in the array.  If you're asked for element 6 and there are only 5 elements in the stack, return null.)

Comment: (I can guarantee that you will have some off-by-one problems, but that's how you learn.)